# Change CSS from TextBox With ID using Master Page

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net

I've changed my css from an element into a master page.

But in my css, i need to put ContentPlaceHolder1_ to apply the changes.

Anyone know how can i avoid this (To use contentplaceholder_1) before element ID).

**CSS**

```
/* LOGIN */
.login #ContentPlaceHolder1_lbtnCadastrar, #ContentPlaceHolder1_lbCadastrado
{
    font-size: small;
}

.login #ContentPlaceHolder1_btnAcessar
{
    margin-top: 5px;
    float: right;
}
```

**LOGIN PAGE**

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="login">
                        <asp:Label ID="lbEmail" Text="E-mail" runat="server" for="Email" />
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmail" runat="server" class="form-control" placeholder="Digite seu e-mail" />
                        <asp:Label ID="lbSenha" Text="Senha" runat="server" for="Senha" />
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtSenha" runat="server" class="form-control" TextMode="Password"
                            placeholder="Digite sua senha" />
                        <asp:Label ID="lbCadastrado" Text="Não é cadastrado ainda?" runat="server" />
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="lbtnCadastrar" Text="Cadastre-se" runat="server" PostBackUrl="../site/cadastro.aspx" />
                        <asp:Button ID="btnAcessar" Text="Acessar" runat="server" class="btn btn-default"
                            OnClick="btnAcessar_OnClick" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 0):

ASP.net changes, some say mangle, ID and Name attributes to ensure they will be unique on a page if they are in some form of Naming Container. If you know they will be unique and you are .net framework 4 and upwards, you can use `ClientIDMode="static"` (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

E.g:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnAcessar" ClientIDMode="static" Text="Acessar" runat="server" class="btn btn-default"  OnClick="btnAcessar_OnClick" />
```

Will enable you to use:

```
#btnAcessar {/*Styles here*/}
```

It is, however, better practice to use CSS classes where possible. Some people advocate avoiding IDs all together in CSS.